# "4.7.0 Timeout waiting for client input" error Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, smtp

I am having trouble sending mail from several servers with the following error when trying from command line. -> (telnet 25, mail to rcpt to data etc.)

```
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
data
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
test
test test
test etst test
.
451 4.7.0 Timeout waiting for client input
```

Smtp server (Exchange 2013) is in X subnet (lets says 192.168.1.0/24) and the servers are on a different subnet (lets say 192.168.2.0/24).

Server does accept messages from within the subnet also via command line. Same subnet works just fine.

Looks like there is no fragmentation issue between the subnets (ping mail.x.com -f -l 1472) does work fine.

What would you suggest to look at at this point?

Edit: The timeout message appears instantly, for some reason, it does not wait for any amount of time.

Thanks

Comment: Any 3rd party antivirus/antispam products?

Comment: Yes, GFI mail essentials.

Comment: Check it then...it's possible that it is the culprit thinking it needs to drop the connection.

Comment: Actually, it was as simple as that. Just provide the answer and I'll approve ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like an antivirus/antispam 3rd party product is dropping the connection.  Based on your comments it is GFI Mail Essentials.  Check their logs and it should show you that it is denying the connection for some reason.  Resolve that or whitelist internal communications based on subnet and you should be good again.